# Jquery ui modal , pass variable in a form without ajax

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

Hello i try to post some data in a php form with jQuery modal  box

My js

```
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 500,
        width: 650,
        modal: true,

        buttons: {
            Envoyer: function() {
                 $('form#leaveReq').submit();

             return true;

            },
            Ok: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });
```

My Html

My html and php (  i use Code Igniter)

```
      <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
     <?php $attributes = array('id' => 'leaveReq');
  echo form_open('school/parents/addevent', $attributes); ?>        
<p class="validateTips">Veillez remplire tous les champs</p> <br/> 


   <fieldset>
    <label for="name"><b>Date de l'évènement</b> </label> <br/> 
    <select id="message">
          <option>Volvo</option>
            <option>Saab</option>
            <option>Mercedes</option>
            <option>Audi</option>
           </select>        
    <label for="email">Nature du probleme</label> <br/>
        <select>
       <?php 
    foreach ($behaviours as $item):?>           
  <option><?=$item['name'];?></option>
```

Description du problème 
        
        At W3Schools you will find all the Web-building tutorials you need, from

```
     echo $text = $this->input->post('text');
 echo $message = $this->input->post('message');
```

nothing work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look for what @BrandonS said about your names

You NEED attach your modal into your form. try use this:

```
open: function (type, data) {
            // include modal into form
            $(this).parent().appendTo($("form:first"));
        },
```

Comment: and  my  <form> must be open  before or after my #dialog-form ?

Comment: Sorry for take so long, i was busy >.< es you need a form to make a post, and you need "Name" in your items (post only read name not id). use the Open function after `modal:true,` and before buttons (you can use in other places but, just to make a reference =)

Comment: by the way, if you can, use some ajax, will make your live easy! =)

Comment: You don't need your modal inside your form. Because he WILL get out, this is why you need the code that i said in my answer, the code will make your dialog be the first element in the form. Let me know if you got it, and if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do it using ajax. It's easily done in codeigniter.
2. Put the form (+ submit button) in an iframe and wrap the iframe with the jquery-UI dialog. No matter what, you need to post page (or else you do it in ajax);

Answer (score 0):

All of your code isn't here so I am not sure, but first make sure that all helpers and libraries in codeigniter are loaded i.e. form helper.

Also if this is your code then you have a few problems:

1. In your form elements you need a "name" attribute,  so that post has a key to go with the value. right now you have no post elements named message only an ID named message.
2. You have a name label but no name field

Maybe this was just a quick post and you left things out but if not you need to re-read how HTML forms work, basically we can't help you if we don't have all the relevant code.